# How to include external library to omnetpp Makefile

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, zeromq, omnet++

I am new to `omnetpp`. In my source file, I include `zmq.h` header and I can successfully make `Makefile` with `opp_makemake --make-so -f --deep`
Next, running `make` does not give any errors either

```
Creating shared library: out/gcc-release//libtictoc_r.so
```

So I am expecting, that `zmq` library has already been linked.
However, when I run

```
opp_run -l tictoc_r
```

I get

```
<!> Error: Cannot load library 'libtictoc_r.so': ./libtictoc_r.so: undefined symbol: zmq_strerror
```

Thus I doubt if `zmq` library had been linked correctly.
By the way, the header files for `zmq` are located in the standard directory, i.e.
`find /usr/include/ -name "*zmq*"`
returns

```
/usr/include/zmq.h
/usr/include/zmq_utils.h
/usr/include/zmq_addon.hpp
/usr/include/zmq.hpp
```

How could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the header files does not say anything about where the actual shared object file is present. You must add `-lzmq` (or whatever the library is called) to your linker flags in the project.

The easiest way is to create a `makefrag` file in the source folder (where the Makefile is generated) and add

```
LDFLAGS += -lzmq
```

to it. The generated `Makefile` will include the `makefrag` file and that one can add to the linker flags. (the `samples/sockets` example does this too)

You can also add the required extra linker flags in the IDE's project properties dialog.